# White screen when output buffer php on some smartphone only

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, buffer

I am writing a website using bootstrap 4, html 5  and php 7.
The website handle a folder with many pdf files inside.
In order to control the access to the pdf file, i use a php file that output the pdf wanted. 
The folder of pdf is protected with a htaccess file.

Everything is working perfectly expect on some smartphones which display a white screen instead of the pdf file.

Same for the download option.

For debugging, I added logs at each steps,
In the normal situation, where i get the pdf, i got "-9-13-"
In the situation with the white screen, i got "-9-13-16", so something weird with the "exit"

Any ideas ?

```
        if (file_exists($file)) 
        {
            //log_dbg('9-');
            if(isset($_POST['download']))//download
            {
                //log_dbg('10-');
                header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $chapter_file_name . '"');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                readfile($file);
                //log_dbg('11-');
                exit;
                //log_dbg('12-');
            }
            else    //Stream
            {

                header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $chapter_file_name . '"');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
                readfile($file);
                //log_dbg('13-');
                exit;
                //log_dbg('14-');

            }
        }
        else
        {
            //log_dbg('15-');
            echo 'Fichier '.$file.' introuvable';
        }
       //log_dbg('16-');
```

Do you have any idea what can be the problem ?

You can try in real here :
http://laguildedesecrivains.fr/story.php -> click on "Chapitre 1"

Comment: checkout your stream.php, it creates problem

Comment: I added logs info (see updated post), but I still don't understand the problem